# Trying to assign jQuery value with if statement

Tags: jquery, variables, if-statement

I have different "drawers" that slide open and closed in response to navigation links on my page.  I'm using some jQuery to flip them open and closed, and change the page background and link colors depending on which "drawer" is open.

I'm also using some jQuery to fade the hover color on the links.  Everything is working fine, except for getting the link to return to the NEW base color on mouseout.  It always defaults to the original css value.  So, I know I have to go into the following and change the .mouseout color depending on which color I want the link to return to on mouseout.

If I just set a variable like in the following example, all is well, it works beautifully.

```
    var originalColor = "#123456";

    jQuery.fn.linkFader = function(settings) {
      settings = jQuery.extend({
        returnColor: originalColor,
        color: '#8dc63f',
        duration: 600
      }, settings);
      return this.each(function() {
        $(this).mouseover(function() { $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ color: settings.color },settings.duration); });
        $(this).mouseout(function() { $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ color: settings.returnColor },settings.duration); });
        $(this).click(function() { $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ color: settings.color },settings.duration); });
      });
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.fader').linkFader({
      });
    });
```

BUT... If I try to assign the variable "originalColor" like the following, it fails.  I need the script to figure out which "drawer" is open, and set the variable to the proper color.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
      var originalColor='';
      if($('#drawerA').is(":visible")){
        var originalColor = "#123456";
      }

      if($('#drawerB').is(":visible")){
        var originalColor = "#456789";
      }
```

Comment: Perhaps neither drawer is visible, and so neither if statement gets triggered?  You may try an `if/else` instead of 2 `if`s.  If I'm right, it will always take the `else` clause.

Comment: Assuming one of them is visible, it should work, but you don't really want the `var` keyword in front of the assignments in the `if` statement bodies.

Comment: "drawerA" is visible by default.

Comment: @Rob you sure? Add an `alert('A')` to the case where drawer A is visible and make sure that code is running.

Comment: Rob, how is `#drawerB` hidden? `display: none?`, `visibility: hidden` ?

Comment: It's hidden with display: none

Comment: @Rob what version of JQuery are you running?

Comment: @Rob - That's probably the problem. Elements with `visibility: hidden` are considered visible. http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: Upon further investigation I second @JamesAllardice answer: "Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout."

Comment: @Cranio I'm running 1.7.2

The else statement works, but, it ALWAYS takes the else statement

Comment: Yes, but, it's hidden with display: none;  I'm toggling with slideDown() & slideUp()

Answer (score 2):

*Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered **visible**, since they still consume space in the layout.* - [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

That's why your 2nd if always gets hit.

You have to hide it with `display: none`

**FYI**

Visible elements are elements that are **not**:

- set to `display:none`
- form elements with `type="hidden"`
- Width and height set to `0`
- A hidden parent element (this also hides child elements)

Comment: It is hidden with display: none

Comment: Sure it is. Exactly according to list

Comment: Yes, so, if the method of hiding the div is proper.  Why is my code not working?

Comment: Ok, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/jbCNf/55/

I Have it set so that there's a one variable original color.  I want the links to fade back to whatever the color of the page they are on.  My theory was to use the if statement to figure out which div was visible.  I've also tried changing the originalColor variable in the functions that slide the divs but that didn't work either.